# Angular 2 Http: Why doesn't try catch mechanism work?

Tags: angular

I wrote the following code in Angular 2 project:

```
ngOnInit () {
    try {
      this.http.request("http://29.media.tumblr.com/ZabOTt2mpdp8ljaxp88lwdhP_400.jpg").subscribe((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res.url);
        this.urls.push(res.url);
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }
```

Well, the path "http://29.media..." is broken. I'd expect that the code inside the try block creates an error and then the code inside catch block will be activated. But no. What I got is an Error. Do you know why?

By the way, there is no Same-Origin-Policy issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is async like a promise. The function has already returned before any exception is thrown.

You can use

```
...subscribe(
  res => {
  },
  err => {
  })
```